# Getting ValueError: while using encrypt and decrypt using Django and Python

Tags: python, django, encryption

I am getting the following error while trying to encrypt my string type value.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/opt/lampp/htdocs/d30/carClinic_vulnerable/bookingservice/views.py", line 141, in signsave
    obj = AES.new('this is a carkey123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 94, in new
    return AESCipher(key, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 59, in __init__
    blockalgo.BlockAlgo.__init__(self, _AES, key, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py", line 141, in __init__
    self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs)
ValueError: AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long
```

Here is my code:

```
name = request.POST.get('uname')
obj = AES.new('this is a carkey123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
enpass = obj.encrypt(name)
```

Comment: The error should be somewhat self explanatory. The [key argument](http://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Cipher.AES-module.html#new) should be a byte string either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long. Yours is 19 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in plain letters in the error message:

> "AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long".

Your key ('this is a carkey123') is 19 bytes long, use a key that's either 16, 24 or 32 bytes long instead.

Comment: I did as per you but its throwing this `Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length` error.

Comment: I used `this is a carkey` key.

Comment: Works for me with "this is a carkey" as key (Python  2.7.6, Crypto 2.6.1).

Comment: I am giving the input as `123456`.

Comment: Ah sorry didn't get the point on "Input strings". Same thing here, the string to encrypt must have a length that's a multiple of 16. Honestly I don't get what you find unclear about those error messages... Pad your input to the nearest higher multiple of 16 and that's it.

Comment: Yes I did and saved that value into db. But when I am again comparing that value with db value after encrypting its throwing this `utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbd in position 6: invalid start byte. You passed in '\x1b\xd4\xad+$M\xbd\xa8\xb3n\xa2\xf2\r\xe8n\x01' (<type 'str'>)` error.